# Paging data in dolphindb

Tags: dolphindb

In dolphindb, do I have a way to paginate data, such as getting data from 100 to 200 rows of a table, just like `select * from table limit 100,100` in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Use `top` clause in DolphinDB to handle data paging.

(1) select top N rows of result set.

```
select top 100 * from table
```

(2) select rows from #100 to #200 (exclusive)

```
select top 100:200 * from table
```